# Arch Linux - Elan Touchpad detected and all drivers installed, but not working

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, touchpad, synaptic, libinput

I've seen lots of problems similar to this, but none which had the touchpad detected and drivers installed, and still not working.

I'm trying to install Arch for the first time on a new laptop, and I can't seem to get the touchpad working. The laptop is the `Lenovo Ideapad 7`, and here's some info, if I'm missing something, let me know and I'll add it.

`uname -a`:

```
Linux <compname> 5.14.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun, 26 Sep 2021 19:36:15 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

As you can see, I have `Elan Touchpad` shows up properly.

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep touchpad`

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=0007 Version=0000
N: Name="Elan Touchpad"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-ELAN0000:00/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 mouse0
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=663800013000003
```

`cat /sys/class/input/event*/device/name`

```
Lid Switch
Elan Touchpad
Power Button
Sleep Button
Power Button
AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Intel HID events
Ideapad extra buttons
Video Bus
Integrated Camera: Integrated C
Integrated Camera: Integrated I
```

Once again, `Elan Touchpad` shows up, so I know it's detected by the system

Now, things I've installed:

```
libinput
synaptics
xinput
libinput-gestures
xf86-input-libinput
```

I might have installed a few other things, but those are the main ones I remember

Next, config I've tried/messed with:
I tried making `40-libinput.conf` and `70-synaptics.conf` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` (out of the example files in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`).
I tried editing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` to have `i8042.reset` in it, then updating grub.
I tried checking in BIOS to see if there's an option to enable/disable it.
I tried checking settings to make sure it's enabled.
I know it's sending input, since when I boot from the ISO on the USB, if I move my finger on the touchpad, it prints a bunch of errors or something about input.
Once again, I also might have changed some other things that I've forgotten, sorry about that, but none of them changed anything, so they hopefully shouldn't make a difference.

I don't really know what else to try. One thing that could work is the solution to [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233792) forum post, but it says something about building the kernel, and that just seems way above my skill level. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and that [topic](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=268508) helps me.

**TL;DR**
Create *blacklist.conf* or modify in path:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

put this to file:

```
blacklist elan_i2c
```

*elan_i2c* was retrieved by:

```
journalctl | grep elan
```

**P.S.** It was tested on 5.10.16-arch1-1 kernel version.